# Collecting and retrieving the principal variation from an alphabeta framework

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am trying to write a chess engine in python, i can find the best move given a position, but i am struggling to collect the principal variation from that position, the following is what i have tried so far:

```
def alphabeta(board, alpha, beta, depth, pvtable):

    if depth == 0:
        return evaluate.eval(board)

    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        score = -alphabeta(board, -beta, -alpha, depth - 1, pvtable)
        board.pop()
        if score >= beta:
            return beta
        if score > alpha:
            alpha = score
            pvtable[depth-1] = str(move)
    return alpha
```

i am using `pvtable[depth - 1] = str(move)` to append moves but in the end i find that `pvtable` contains random non consistent moves, things like `['g1h3', 'g8h6', 'h3g5', 'd8g5']` for the starting position.

I know that similar questions about that have been asked but i still didn't figure out how i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your moves are overwritten when the search reaches the same depth again (in a different branch of the game tree).

This site explains quite good how to retrieve the principal variation: https://web.archive.org/web/20071031100114/http://www.brucemo.com:80/compchess/programming/pv.htm

Applied to your code example, it should be something like this (I didn't test it):

```py
def alphabeta(board, alpha, beta, depth, pline):

    line = []
    if depth == 0:
        return evaluate.eval(board)

    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        score = -alphabeta(board, -beta, -alpha, depth - 1, line)
        board.pop()
        if score >= beta:
            return beta
        if score > alpha:
            alpha = score
        pline[:] = [str(move)] + line

    return alpha
```

Comment: Thanks, i already read this page, it's interesting however i couldn't translate that into python code since my background on C is 0, can you give me an example?

Comment: Thank you very much, i just edited that to `if score > alpha: alpha = score pline[:] = [str(move)] + line`, it looks okay but still not sure if that is the right approach

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your comment. Why do you still think that this approach is not the right one? If you have further questions, just write me a PM. Otherwise feel free to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, i just meant that i need to do more tests to check whether or not what i am getting are consistent and related moves.